# How to get corresponding data from different arrays

Tags: java

I have 2 arrays that have corresponding data, one has 20 names and another 20 grades, Im asking the user to enter a name and then taking the name and matching it up to the grades file and returning the grade, how would I go about doing that.

Ive tried doing something like this then returning g which refers to grade and getName refers to the name input from the user.  Also getName is a string and g is an int array.

```
getName.length() = g.length;
```

Would I have to scan through the grades file to find that exact line with the corresponding grade? Im not really sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Please post all the code that you have tried, and which does not seem to work. Also, what is getName? What type of array is `g`, and what are its contents?

Comment: use int index=usernames.indexOf(username) and to get corresponding grade by grades(index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question does not provide the relevant data, I'll try to answer your question with my own variable names, and you can cross check my code with yours.

Assuming the names are stored in the String array `names[]`, and the marks are in the int array `marks[]`, and `getName` contains the name to be found,

```
int FoundMarks = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    if(names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(getName))
    {
        FoundMarks = marks[i];
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Marks of "+getName+": "+FoundMarks);
```

This is a simple Linear Search which takes each individual name of `names` and checks if the user is searching for that particular one. If found, then the marks of that person is stored in `FoundMarks`, and the looping stops.

This type of searching algorithm will be incredibly useful in almost all array related operations.

**I repeat**, the variable names might be different than yours, but the core logic remains the same.